# Javascript destroy img objects - but img is still in resources

Tags: javascript, performance, resources

I am writing single page application which displays lot of images.
I have problem with consumption of memory by browser because he still remember images which I deleted from DOM (and img objects destroyed) from page.

In development toolbar I can still see in Resources the images which are not displayed yet.
Test it in Chrome and Safari.

Is there any way how to release these images?

Comment: how do you know those images are using RAM?

Comment: If I look on processes the memory still increase with loading new images and release old one.

Comment: the resources tab is not a live snapshot, it's more of a log, and chrome manages memory for you; if it's indeed keeping images in ram, that's because you have plenty of free ram available.

Comment: But is it normal, that one instance of chrome consume 4GB of ram?

Comment: No, 4gb is higher than normal. resources isn't really the right tool for finding memory leaks (which you could have). Use the Profile (heap stuff) and Timeline tools to track live ram utilization. Also checkout out the tab's different memory uses in the chrome task manager. Lastly, 4gb is high, but it doesn't neccessarily mean there's a problem, the machine might have enough RAM that it doesn't bother recovering those 4gb...